# Python When to use <> and when != operator

Tags: python

I didn't find much info on the web (or may be one is deprecated ?). Is there a use preference/case for one operator over the other ? It looks from some docs on the web that they are similar...

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: <> is not valid python3 and is a holdover from 1.5.2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... Yes, duplicate indeed... Somehow didn't find this while searching... holding off...

Comment: @iamauser: when searching for syntax consisting of punctuation, make sure you use quotes; [`python "!=" "<>" is:q`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22%21%3D%22+%22%3C%3E%22+is%3Aq) gives a list of questions mentioning both.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will keep this in mind... Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 1):

Always use the "!=" form.

The two forms are equivalent in Python 2 and previous versions, because of the Languages the original Python inherited from (features from Basic, ABC and C) - but since then (1991), the "!=" form was preferred, and "<>" deprecated, since most imperative languages use this operator (the same one used in "C") and to avoid two different ways of performing the same operation.

It is interesting to note that the "<>" note has been deprecated and is not valid at all in Python 3, so the "!=" operator is the official one to be used in new code.

Comment: so, they started off as different in ancient python version(s) ?

Comment: No, they always where the samething.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<>` when you want to pretend you are coding in BASIC. Hey, look, `print` is a statement!

Use `!=` at other times. It's the only inequality operator supported in Python 3.x (`<>` has been removed).